# How to ask questions with "how many" in them?

Tags: grammar, questions

I would like some guidance on how to ask questions with "how many" in them. For example, does one say

> From how many minutes is the train late?

or simply

> How many minutes is the train late?

or something else?

Similarly, is it

> From how many kilos does she slim ?

or something else?

Comment: @Philoto below has given you the suggestion "How slim is she" to replace "From how many kilos does she slim?". _Slim_ can be a verb, but usually more like, "She's trying to slim down this summer," meaning to lose weight - so I suspect you're really trying to ask, "How many kilos did she weigh before?" [before she lost the weight]. And remember - be careful when talking about how much someone weighs; "she looks great!" is usually better if you're not sure than blurting out "how many kilos has she lost?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How many minutes will the train be late?

would be ok. *From* is incorrect in this question.

> From how many kilos does she slim

I'm not sure *slim* can be measured like this. Your best bet will be *How slim is she?*

Generally, you'll be just putting *how* in front of the question and changing word order accordingly to make your sentence a question.

> She has many friends.
>
> How many friends does she have?

If there's a preposition somewhere in the statement and it is connected with *many* or the noun, you'll want to move it toward the end.

> I've heard this rumor from many people

How many people have you heard this rumor from?

Notice how *from* is separated from *many people* and put in the end of question. Strictly speaking, *From how many people have you heard this rumor?* is also ok grammatically, but in my opinion it is a little more awkward.

Answer (score 0):

I would not normally use "how many" with units of measurement like minutes or kilos.    Instead, I would rephrase as how+(adjective):

> How late is the train?
>   How slim is she?
>   (Contrast using "how many" for discrete items: How many apples did we have?  How many people ate them?)

The exception would be if I wanted to emphasize that this unit of measurement should be used:

> A: How late is the train?
>   B: It's only a little late.
>   A: I know that, but how many minutes late is it?